# I want to add git credentials in jenkins pipeline, which take a file from particular branch and add to our current jenkins pipeline

Tags: go, jenkins, dependencies, glide-golang

I have the pl and pl_client git repository as a private  in that two repository i am using the go language  and in pl_client i am just installing the dependencies  with the command go get all for that dependencies it asking the access for the pl git repository to go get dependencies

I tried all types of credentials given in Jenkins all fails

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.